# What is the intersection of a single set?

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm currently reading through some set theory questions for a statistics class and I came across the following notation that I've never seen before, and I can't seem to find anywhere else online. The equation in question is:
$$
\mathcal{B} = \cap\{\mathcal{E}:\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{E} \text{ and } \mathcal{E} \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-field}\}
$$
My question is, what does the intersection symbol in front of the set builder notation mean? How can I take the intersection of only one set? I would ask my professor, but they don't have any office hours today and I'd rather not wait too long for what seems like a simple question.

Comment: Probably the intersection of all the valid $\mathcal E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\cap A$ usually denotes the intersection of all the sets that are contained in $A$,
although not everyone uses this notation.
Using the more common notion of an intersection over an index set, this means that

$$
\cap A = \bigcap_{B\in A} B
$$
holds, and that $A$ is a set of sets.

In your case, this means
$$
\mathcal{B} = \cap\{\mathcal{E}:\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{E} \text{ and } \mathcal{E} \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-field}\}
= \bigcap_{\mathcal{E}:\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{E} \text{ and } \mathcal{E} \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-field}} \mathcal{E}
$$

Comment: So in this case, the result would be the smallest such $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: @GideonTveten yes

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense.